# How to implement LDAP authentication

Tags: go, authentication, ldap, go-guardian

My task is to implement LDAP authentication a monitoring tool called sensu-uchiwa since it doesn't implement it by default. To learn LDAP and Go, I started a small demo project, a simple API that requires LDAP authentication. I uses this package g[o get github.com/shaj13/go-guardian](http://go%20get%20github.com/shaj13/go-guardian)

Here is my sample LDAP implementation

```
func setupGoGuardian() {
 cfg := &ldap.Config{
    Port:         "389",
    Host:         "ldapadmin.test",
    TLS:          &tls.Config{},
    BindDN:       "cn=olivia,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test",
    BindPassword: "root",
    Attributes:   []string{},
    BaseDN:       "dc=ldapadmin, dc=test",
    Filter:       "(uid=%s)",
 }
 authenticator = auth.New()
 cache = store.NewFIFO(context.Background(), time.Minute*10)
 strategy := ldap.NewCached(cfg, cache)
 authenticator.EnableStrategy(ldap.StrategyKey, strategy)
}
```

I actually installed phpldadmin in my local machine, just to understand more.In the admin panel, I create a user called John with password John see screenshot

[image]

Now I tried to call the api

```
  curl  -k http://127.0.0.1:8081/v1/book/1449311601 -u john:john
```

I still unauthorized.
Before using the local ldapadmin, I tried the online ldap test server [ldap server](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)
with the following configuration

```
cfg := &ldap.Config{
    BaseDN:       "dc=example, dc=com",
    BindDN:       "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com",
    Port:         "389",
    Host:         "ldap.forumsys.com",
    BindPassword: "password",
    Filter:       "(uid=%s)",
}
```

And it works well.
Now I know I missed or I have done something wrong in my code, but because I am new both to Go and ldap, I need help to figure it out to make work.

Here is the whole main.go

```
     package main

     import (
         "context"
         "crypto/tls"
         "fmt"
         "log"
         "net/http"
         "time"

         "github.com/gorilla/mux"
         "github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/auth"
         "github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/auth/strategies/ldap"
         "github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/store"
    )

    var authenticator auth.Authenticator
    var cache store.Cache

    func main() {
       setupGoGuardian()
       router := mux.NewRouter()
       router.HandleFunc("/", getDefault).Methods("GET")
       router.HandleFunc("/v1/book/{id}", 
     middleware(http.HandlerFunc(getBookAuthor))).Methods("GET")
       log.Println("server started and listening on 
       http://127.0.0.1:8081")
       http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8081", router)
    }

    func getDefault(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      fmt.Println("Ok default homepage")
      w.Write([]byte("Homepage"))
    }

    func getBookAuthor(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      vars := mux.Vars(r)
      id := vars["id"]
      books := map[string]string{
        "1449311601": "Laura",
        "1484250956x": "Yoman",
        "1484220498": "Skill",
      }
      body := fmt.Sprintf("Author: %s \n", books[id])
      w.Write([]byte(body))
    }

    func setupGoGuardian() {
   //cfg := &ldap.Config{
   //   BaseDN:       "dc=example, dc=com",
   //   BindDN:       "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com",
   //   Port:         "389",
   //   Host:         "ldap.forumsys.com",
   //   BindPassword: "password",
   //   Filter:       "(uid=%s)",
   // }
    cfg := &ldap.Config{
      Port:         "389",
      Host:         "ldapadmin.test/phpldapadmin",
      TLS:          &tls.Config{},
      BindDN:       "cn=olivia,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test",
      BindPassword: "root",
      Attributes:   []string{},
      BaseDN:       "dc=ldapadmin, dc=test",
      Filter:       "(uid=%s)",
    }
    authenticator = auth.New()
    cache = store.NewFIFO(context.Background(), time.Minute*10)
   strategy := ldap.NewCached(cfg, cache)
   authenticator.EnableStrategy(ldap.StrategyKey, strategy)
 }

 func middleware(next http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Executing Auth Middleware")
    user, err := authenticator.Authenticate(r)
    if err != nil {
        code := http.StatusUnauthorized
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(code), code)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("User %s Authenticated\n", user.UserName())
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

My local ldap server is hosted at `ldapadmin.test/phpldapadmin`

Now when running `slapcat` inside my ubunut20 machine, the results are

```
        dn: dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: top
        objectClass: dcObject
        objectClass: organization
        o: tesldap
        dc: ldapadmin
        structuralObjectClass: organization
        entryUUID: 001f85be-92c9-103b-9d45-bb8a7b47e3b6
        creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        createTimestamp: 20210816103228Z
        entryCSN: 20210816103228.907585Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816103228Z

        dn: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
        objectClass: organizationalRole
        cn: admin
        description: LDAP administrator
        userPassword:: e1NTSEF9M1V2a3ZLWlFlSStHVUdKQ0U0bzlneFpiRGZVcklsTUo=
        structuralObjectClass: organizationalRole
        entryUUID: 002078d4-92c9-103b-9d46-bb8a7b47e3b6
        creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        createTimestamp: 20210816103228Z
        entryCSN: 20210816103228.913850Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816103228Z

        dn: ou=people,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: organizationalUnit
        objectClass: top
        ou: people
        structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
        entryUUID: 432694c6-92d1-103b-806c-51a5a293746f
        creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        createTimestamp: 20210816113137Z
        entryCSN: 20210816113137.335074Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816113137Z

        dn: ou=groups,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: organizationalUnit
        objectClass: top
        ou: groups
        structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
        entryUUID: 432774a4-92d1-103b-806d-51a5a293746f
        creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        createTimestamp: 20210816113137Z
        entryCSN: 20210816113137.340805Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816113137Z

        dn: uid=olivia,ou=people,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: inetOrgPerson
        objectClass: posixAccount
        objectClass: shadowAccount
        uid: olivia
        cn: olivia
        sn: Nightingale
        loginShell: /bin/bash
        uidNumber: 10000
        gidNumber: 10000
        homeDirectory: /home/olivia
        shadowMax: 60
        shadowMin: 1
        shadowWarning: 7
        shadowInactive: 7
        shadowLastChange: 0
        structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
        entryUUID: a4283248-92d1-103b-806f-51a5a293746f
        creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        createTimestamp: 20210816113420Z
        userPassword:: e1NTSEF9Q3hOYWFQdnJEVW84dVRjNnhYKzM1MlFZcmlyRmk0Q0o=
        entryCSN: 20210816113506.981478Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816113506Z

        dn: cn=olivia,ou=groups,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: posixGroup
        cn: olivia
        gidNumber: 10000
        memberUid: olivia
        structuralObjectClass: posixGroup
        entryUUID: a428afd4-92d1-103b-8070-51a5a293746f
        creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        createTimestamp: 20210816113420Z
        entryCSN: 20210816113420.087860Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816113420Z

        dn: cn=readonly,ou=people,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        objectClass: organizationalRole
        objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
        cn: readonly
        userPassword:: e1NTSEF9RE5LUEdBMVdtdGtQVDVwRlRCb2NlS2pOQlpndGtKMy8=
        description: Bind DN user for LDAP Operations
        structuralObjectClass: organizationalRole
        entryUUID: 39528972-92d2-103b-8071-51a5a293746f
        creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        createTimestamp: 20210816113830Z
        entryCSN: 20210816113830.342653Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816113830Z

        dn: cn=john doe,ou=people,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        cn: john doe
        givenName: john
        gidNumber: 10000
        homeDirectory: /home/users/jdoe
        sn: doe
        loginShell: /bin/sh
        objectClass: inetOrgPerson
        objectClass: posixAccount
        objectClass: top
        userPassword:: e01ENX1VbnZWdGRhSjRzTXE2WFRHSXAvM2hRPT0=
        uidNumber: 1000
        uid: jdoe
        structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
        entryUUID: a8633cf2-92dd-103b-8a45-b796d7b82159
        creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        createTimestamp: 20210816130021Z
        entryCSN: 20210816130021.143200Z#000000#000#000000
        modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test
        modifyTimestamp: 20210816130021Z
```

Comment: From the question, it's not clear, whether you want to implement authentication on the client side or on the server side.

Comment: Hi @kostix yes actually the api is written in go, and we will have a frontend that will call the go api that requires authentication using ldap.

Comment: Sorry, but this did not make it any clearer for me. Do you have a task of creating "a Go API" which implements LDAP protocol and requires authentication? If yes, are you tasked with actually implementing LDAP authentication _there?_

Comment: Hi @kostix, yes. I updated my question to show the main.go file

Comment: So you mean a client makes a request to your Go program, and it's supposed to authenticate the client against an external LDAP server?

Comment: @kostix yes. Thats the goal.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have incorrect configuration . After reading this link https://campus.barracuda.com/product/essentials/doc/3211273/how-to-configure-user-authentication-using-ldap/

I updated my ldap config

```
    cfg := &ldap.Config{
        Port:         "389",
        Host:         "ldapadmin.test",
        BindDN:       "cn=admin,dc=ldapadmin,dc=test",
        BindPassword: "root",
        BaseDN:       "dc=ldapadmin, dc=test",
        Filter:       "(uid=%s)",
    }
```